# Agile rails development book, Depot rake test 2 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm have been trying to solve this issue for a while now, but without any luck. I'm going thru the Agile rails developmnet book and when I run rake test I get 2 errors at Iteration B1 Validating:

```
Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80create
test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in   <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'                                                 

Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_update_product:
 URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):  http://www.example.com:80update
test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

Can someone please help me solve this!!!

Products>controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

 class ProductsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @product = products(:one)
    @update = {
       title:       'Lorem Ipsum',
      description: 'Wibbles are fun!',
      image_url:   'lorem.jpg',
      price:       19.95
    }
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get products_url
   assert_response :success
  end

 test "should get new" do
    get new_product_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create product" do
    assert_difference('Product.count') do
      post :create, product: @update
    end

    assert_redirected_to product_url(Product.last)
  end

  test "should show product" do
    get product_url(@product)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_product_url(@product)
     assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update product" do
    put :update, id: @product, product: @update
    assert_redirected_to product_url(@product)
   end

  test "should destroy product" do
    assert_difference('Product.count', -1) do
      delete product_url(@product)
    end

    assert_redirected_to products_url
  end
 end
```

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

     respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
         format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was      successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
   def destroy
     @product.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was   successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end

  private
     # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
 end
```

products.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
   validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}  
# 
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
     with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
    } 
  end
```